# How to allow actions in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, authentication

I make something horribly wrong in Cake 2.3.6 stable. I followed the Auth tutorial and added in the AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
```

But when I enter the site on the homepage, cake throws that I´m not authorized to access that location.

With no effect I tried in the PagesController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
}
```

I double checked the tutorial and my code, there are no differences except I had to swap "$this->Post" with "$this->Calclulation" in CalculationsController. 
Furthermore the login- and logout-redirects in AppController doesn´t work.

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'calculations', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => ''),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

How could it be solved? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check default routers. app/Config/routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

this mean, that home page is actulay rendered by  pages controller and action display,
so, you should allow  display

```
$this->Auth->allow('display');
```

Comment: wow, you are genius, that was it :) thanks :) But seriously that should be reported to the Cake dev-team to be implemented into the tutorial as I really followed the tutorial and nothing else.

Comment: I was stuck on this problem as well you are amazing! thank you!